# Add property to one of the form fields in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a special `template` property to one of the form fields which I will than use to render the form in template tag. Here is the code:

```
form = ProfileForm()

for field in form:
    if field.name == 'email':
       field.template = 'email_field.html'
```

This way, original `form` variable is not modified. Is there a way to achive my goal?

Comment: Please provide some more insight on what’s not working here as you imagined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you might want to build a html5 email field:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import Widget
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class Html5Email(Widget):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        return mark_safe(u'<input name="custom-email" type="email" />')


class YourForm(forms.Form):
    html5_email = forms.CharField(widget=Html5Email())
```

I came up with the above by glancing at the Django source code.  Since I haven't personally use the above in an actual project, the code will probably need to be fleshed out.